# How to extract, access and use all values of a list at chosen sublist index?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My question is the result of the issue I'm fighting with at the moment. What I need to do is to use something like that:

```py
if myString in list[][1]:
   do something
```

...on a structure like that:

```
[
[object1Name, string_1, string_2],
[object2Name, string_1, string_2],
[object3Name, string_1, string_2],
[object4Name, string_1, string_2]
]
```

I need to check if myString is equal to string_1 in any of the top-level list items and (later) also get the index of top-level list items that fulfill the condition.

I am aware that I can implement it using additional for loop with if statement inside to cycle through all elements in top-level list but I wan't to avoid that. I want a one-liner preferably with "in" but if it's not possible anything else.

I also need to do the exact same thing for dictionary instead of list (which I hope will use more or less same solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `any(..)` here:

```
if any(myString == sublist[1] for sublist in lst):
    # ... do something
    pass
```

for an iterable of dictionaries, it is exactly the same, except that the key might be a non-integer, like:

```
if any(myString == subdict[some_key] for subdict in lst):
    # ... do something
    pass
```

We here thus iterate over the `sublist`s in `lst`. If for one of the `sublist`s, `myString == sublist[1]`, then this will succeed, otherwise it will fail.

We thus here use a generator. The `any(..)` will stop from the moment it finds an item that is `True`. This however still runs in linear time (worst case).

**EDIT**: We can obtain the first index with:

```
idx = next((idx for idx, sublist in enumerate(lst) if myString == sublist[1]), None)
```

this will return `None` if no such index is present.

or we can retrieve all the indices with list comprehension:

```
idcs = [idx for idx, sublist in enumerate(lst) if myString == sublist[1]]
```

Comment: What about getting the index of top-level list item that fulfills such condition?

Comment: Using Your exact code (index part) my interpreter choked with "Generator expression must be parenthesized". I used Your code 1 to 1, only replacing lst and myString with my list and my string respectively.

Comment: @NecXelos: that's indeed correct, you should add parenthesis to the generator.

Comment: Second solution (idcs one) worked properly. Error mentioned above only happens with first solution (idx one).

Comment: @NecXelos: yes, but by adding brackets, as in the edited answer, it should be resolved.

Comment: I added () in next(( idx and in [1]), None and it indeed worked properly. I had no idea what this None is at the end that's why I didn't know where those () are supposed to go initially.

Please edit Your answer with those parenthesis fixed and I'll mark it as answer :) Thank You very much, You're awesome!

Comment: @NecXelos: the `None` is the "fallback" value in case it can not find such index.